# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Article' not found Laravel 5.6

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-5.6

I have a "basic" problem, but I can't figure where.

I have a problem between the controller and the model.

I went on the Internet and I saw a lot of "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App{something}' not found" solved problem, but none worked for me.

Could it be because I did a copy-past form my native project?
I'm only looking for the "index" part. I can't work on the rest since I can't see what I'm doing.

MyController:

```
<?php

namespace App;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Article;


class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        session_start();

        $article = App\Article::Blog();

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        session_start();

        // si je reçois des données de formulaire,
        if (isset($_POST['titre'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['contenu'])
        ){
            $admin = Add();

            // si la création a réussi,
            if ($add) {
                //rediriger vers
                header('location: /Chef/Controleur/controleur-blog.php');
                echo "Well done!". '<br>';
                echo "You have add an article!";
            }
        }
        else {
            // afficher le formulaire

            echo "Error. Please try again.";
            require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur_piedpage.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        require __DIR__.'/../Modele/modele.php';

        $article = Article();

        // si je reçois des données de formulaire,
        if (isset($_POST['titre'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['contenu'])){
            $admin = Edit();

            // si la création a réussi,
            if ($edit) {
                //rediriger vers
            header('location: /Chef/Controleur/controleur-blog.php');
            echo "You have edit an article!";
        }
        }
        else {
        // afficher le formulaire
        require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur-entete.php';
        require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur-recherche.php';   
        require __DIR__.'/../Vue/edit.php';
        echo "Error. Please try again.";
        require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur_piedpage.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        require __DIR__.'/../Modele/modele.php';

        $admin = Delete();
        $article = Article();

        if ($delete) {
            //rediriger vers
        header('location: /Chef/Controleur/controleur-blog.php');
        }
        else {
            // afficher le formulaire
            require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur-entete.php';
            require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur-recherche.php';   
            require __DIR__.'/../Vue/delete.php';
            echo "Error. Please try again.";
            require __DIR__.'/Controleur/controleur_piedpage.php';
        }
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {
    function Blog() {
        if(isset($_POST['register'])) if(('role'== 0) && ('role' == 1)) {
            $todoread = [];
            $pdo = prepareStatement('SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100');
            $pdo->execute();

            $todoread = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $todoread;
        }
    }

    function Edit(){
        $pdo_statement = prepareStatement('UPDATE article
                                            SET titre=:titre, description=:description, contenu =:contenu
                                            WHERE id=:id');

        $pdo_statement->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
        $pdo_statement->bindParam(':titre', $_POST['titre']);
        $pdo_statement->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
        $pdo_statement->bindParam(':contenu', $_POST['contenu']);
        $pdo_statement->execute();

        return true;
    }

    function Article(){
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = :id";
            $article = prepareStatement($sql);       
            $article->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
            $article->execute();
            return $article->fetch();
        }
    }

    function Delete() {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $pdo_statement = prepareStatement('DELETE FROM article WHERE  id =:id');
            $pdo_statement->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
            $pdo_statement->execute();
            $pdo_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function Add(){
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $pdo_statement = prepareStatement(
                'INSERT INTO article (titre, description, contenu)
                VALUES (:titre, :description, :contenu)');

                $pdo_statement->bindParam(':titre', $_POST['titre']);
                $pdo_statement->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
                $pdo_statement->bindParam(':contenu', $_POST['contenu']);
                $pdo_statement->execute();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Blog')
@section('content')
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['nom'])): ?>
<h1 class="center"> Welcome to my blog ! </h1>
<h2 class="center"> Tips, tutorials and more on chatbots, artificials intelligence </h2>
<p>
    To access the blog, please register yourself <br>
    You'll find the link to the registration <a href="/Chef/Controleur/controleur-registration.php"> here</a> or you can login  <a href="/Chef/Controleur/controleur-login.php"> here</a>.
</p>
<?php else: ?>
<h1 class="center"> Welcome to my blog <?= $_SESSION ['nom'] ?> ! </h1>
<h2 class="center"> Enjoy the tips and tutorials of this blog! </h2>
<br>
<button class="ui small black button"> <a href="/Chef/Controleur/controleur-add.php"> Add an article </button> </a>
<br>
<?php
foreach ($blog as $ligne) {
?>
<br>
<button class="ui small black button"> <a href="/Chef/Controleur/controleur-edit?id=<?php echo $ligne["id"]; ?>"> Edit the article</button> </a>
<button class="ui small black button"> <a href="/Chef/Controleur/controleur-delete?id=<?php echo $ligne["id"]; ?>"> Delete the article </button> </a> <br>
<?php echo $ligne['titre'].'<br>'; ?><br>
<?php echo $ligne['description'].'<br>'; ?><br>
<?php echo $ligne['contenu'].'<br>'; ?> <br> <br> <!-- créer un template : https://openclassrooms.com/courses/adoptez-une-architecture-mvc-en-php/creer-un-template-de-page !-->
<?php
}
?>
<br>
<?php endif; ?>
@endsection
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue, change:

```
<?php

namespace App;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Article;
```

In your controller to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers; // <- removing duplicate namespace

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article; // <- Case sensitive, use App\, not app\
```

Other than that, I would really encourage you to read [the documentation of Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6), because this code is not really using Laravel.

You do not have to use `session_start()` as in Laravel you have [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session).

You do not have to work with superglobals as `$_POST`, because you can use Laravel's [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests) objects.

You should not handle request data in your models, that's what your controller and/or services are for, this layer (request data) should not 'bleed' into your models like this.

You are using PDO statements, and totally bypass Laravel's [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent).

I also see a lot of conditional requires, something that you should not do if you were using Laravel's [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container).

With all of this, you are practically skipping every bit of functionality of Laravel and you are basically using the entire framework just for routing.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your method. I'll tell you if it worked. For my model, I did a copy-past of a native project. For the future, will it be good this way (by doing a copy-past of an existing project), or is it better to start over?

Comment: I would suggest starting over, you are creating some hybrid right now, which is not using Laravel. I would check the Laravel docs and e.g. laracasts.com, do some tuturials and then migrate (don't copy/paste) your project to Laravel.